# Stripe Connect - How do I use tokens in the most secure fashion to pass sensitive data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am building a stripe backend where users will be able to create custom connect accounts with stripes api. I am using `react` as my frontend. I am trying to understand the most secure way to do this. Below is what I am doing, and I would like to know if someone can either corroborate that this is the proper way to use tokenization or if I am approaching this incorrectly?

`React` sends sensitive data (account numbers and ssn etc) to my `node` server -->

`stripe.tokens.create` in my node server produces a token -->

token is returned to `react` where I then send token to `stripes api` -->

`stripe.accounts.create` creates the account and onboarding finishes with some extra info if need be

Is this the proper use of tokenization? Stripe provides `node` examples to produce tokens so I assumed this was the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about [account tokens](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens) for collecting [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data) without handling the data directly on your servers, you've got it a bit flipped around.

The expected flow is:

1. Load Stripe.js in your client application
2. Have your user [provide their details](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens#details) in your form
3. [Submit those details to Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens#javascript) via Stripe.js and `createToken('account', {...})` to get an account token (or `'person'` for a person token)
4. Use that account token to [create](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens#create-account) or [update](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-account_token) a connected account with the tokenized PII (or a [person](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens#create-person)).

Comment: To make sure I understand, the tokenization process should be occurring in my `react` frontend right? As opposed to sending the data to node to have node do that.

Comment: That's right - the entire point of using tokens is to avoid the tokenized information from being handled directly by your systems.